# JavaScript on HTML table of images

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in which each cell is an image in HTML. I need click functionality so that when you click on an image it takes you to a different HTML sheet linked to the image. I know I need to use JavaScript to do this but any kind of push in the right direction would be helpful. Each image cell in the table has it's own id as well.

```html
<table align="center" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://images.genius.com/0bffd93463afe53e7f651f72bedfc78b.1000x1000x1.jpg" alt="The College Dropout" height="300" width="300" id="a1"></img>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://images.genius.com/2eb75c8a4d53e8782d8e37681871a9bf.1000x1000x1.jpg" alt="Late Registration" height="300" width="300" id="a2"></img>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://images.genius.com/336af3b66a79eb083a8469fa6f5c84c5.1000x1000x1.jpg" alt="Graduation" height="300" width="300" id="a3"></img>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://images.genius.com/f69387025c516715db7b5d56037ee76a.1000x997x1.jpg" alt="808s_&amp_Heartbreak" height="300" width="300" id="a4"></img>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why not wrap your images in an `a` tag in html (ie. `<a href="./myPage.html"><img /></a>`)? (PS. `img` is a self closing html tag, you dont need `</img>`, instead use the single tag `<img src=""... />`)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('table td img');

Array.from(images).forEach(function(img) {
  let tableCell = img.parentNode;
  
  let anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.href = img.getAttribute('src');
  anchor.append(img);
  
  tableCell.append(anchor);
});
```

```html
<table align="center" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://images.genius.com/0bffd93463afe53e7f651f72bedfc78b.1000x1000x1.jpg" alt="The College Dropout" height="300" width="300" id="a1"></img>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://images.genius.com/2eb75c8a4d53e8782d8e37681871a9bf.1000x1000x1.jpg" alt="Late Registration" height="300" width="300" id="a2"></img>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://images.genius.com/336af3b66a79eb083a8469fa6f5c84c5.1000x1000x1.jpg" alt="Graduation" height="300" width="300" id="a3"></img>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://images.genius.com/f69387025c516715db7b5d56037ee76a.1000x997x1.jpg" alt="808s_&amp_Heartbreak" height="300" width="300" id="a4"></img>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward solution is wrapping your  in an  with the appropriate url. See the snippet below.

```html
<table align = "center" style="width:100%">
   <tr> 
    <td> 
      <a href="https://www.google.com/">
        <img src = "http://images.genius.com/0bffd93463afe53e7f651f72bedfc78b.1000x1000x1.jpg" alt="The College Dropout" height="300" width="300" id = "a1"></img>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td> 
      <a href="https://www.google.com/">
        <img src = "https://images.genius.com/2eb75c8a4d53e8782d8e37681871a9bf.1000x1000x1.jpg" alt="Late Registration" height="300" width="300" id = "a2"></img>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td> 
      <a href="https://www.google.com/">
        <img src = "https://images.genius.com/336af3b66a79eb083a8469fa6f5c84c5.1000x1000x1.jpg" alt="Graduation" height="300" width="300" id = "a3"></img>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td> 
      <a href="https://www.google.com/">
        <img src = "https://images.genius.com/f69387025c516715db7b5d56037ee76a.1000x997x1.jpg" alt="808s_&amp_Heartbreak" height="300" width="300" id = "a4"></img>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```